# Jquery: cloning a table and its first row

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a standard table structure like this:

```
<table id="test">
  <th>...</th>
  <tr><td>one thing</td></tr>
  <tr><td>another</td></tr>
  ...
  ...
</table>
```

I know how to clone the entire table, or the nth row of a table, but what I need is the whole thing, EXCEPT the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc row of the table, in other words:

```
<table id="test">
  <th>...</th>
  <tr><td>one thing</td></tr>
</table>
```

Ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I know how to clone the entire table..."*

Then do that, clone the entire table, then remove what you dont need.

A trick to select everything except first child is to use `*+*`. `+` selector in css mean the matching element on right side next to the element on the left side.

In the end, you can use that :

```
var $clone = $('#test').clone().find('tr+tr').remove().end();
```

`$clone` will then be your clone table with only the first row.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the following [child filter](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/) selector: `:not(:first-child)`. But you have plenty other solutions combining all these selectors.

```
var $clone = $("#test").clone();
$clone.find("tr:not(:first-child)").remove();    
$("#target").html($clone);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rnogdu0L/

```js
$("#but").click(function() {
    var $clone = $("#test").clone();
    $clone.find("tr:not(:first-child)").remove();    
    $("#target").html($clone);
});
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#source {
    min-height: 20px;
    background: pink;
}

#target {
    min-height: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source">
    <table id="test">
        <th>do not delete this</th>
        <tr><td>one thing</td></tr>
        <tr><td>another</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="target">
</div>
<button id="but">Clone & Delete</button>
```