# How can i Clone a Table Row and append it to a Table?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I'd like to add Blank rows through a button press to the bottom of my table. so I wrote this code to do so. but Nothing happens when I click the button.

I have the Following Relevant HTML Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $add_button = $('#add_new');
  var $blank_row = $('#blank_row');
  var $time_table = $('#time_table');

  $add_button.click(function() {
    $blank_row.clone().appendTo($time_table);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="time_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th class="time">ST</th>
    <th class="time">TH</th>
    <th class="time">DT</th>
    <th class="time">EX-ST</th>
    <th class="time">EX-TH</th>
    <th class="time">EX-DT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="blank_row">
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="st" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="th" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="dt" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ex_st" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ex_th" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ex_dt" class="time_input"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add_new">Button</button>
```

I've done a bunch of searching but I can't quite grasp what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: cloning a table and its first row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486026/jquery-cloning-a-table-and-its-first-row)

Comment: The problem is that you have declared the add_button without a $, but try to call click function on $add_button. add_button and $add_button are two separate legit variables

Comment: @troelsM.B.jensen Thank you for pointing out my mistake. it works like I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$` before your variables. Use the variable as you have declared it.. Either with or without `$` but use the same name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var add_button = $('#add_new');
  var blank_row = $('#blank_row');
  var time_table = $('#time_table');

  add_button.click(function() {
    blank_row.clone().appendTo(time_table);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="time_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th class="time">ST</th>
    <th class="time">TH</th>
    <th class="time">DT</th>
    <th class="time">EX-ST</th>
    <th class="time">EX-TH</th>
    <th class="time">EX-DT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="blank_row">
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="st" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="th" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="dt" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ex_st" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ex_th" class="time_input"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="ex_dt" class="time_input"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add_new">Button</button>
```

Comment: Joesph  thank you for your help, i feel like a dummy posting this for a silly mistake like that.

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable to `jQuery wrapped object` with prefix your variable with `$`. It makes reading the code easier to know which variables are jQuery wrapped.

```
var $add_button = $('#add_new');
var $blank_row = $('#blank_row');
var $time_table = $('#time_table');
```

Please find below snippet for more info.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var $add_button = $('#add_new');
        var $blank_row = $('#blank_row');
        var $time_table = $('#time_table');

        $add_button.click(function() {
            $blank_row.clone().appendTo($time_table);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="time_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th class="time">ST</th>
        <th class="time">TH</th>
        <th class="time">DT</th>
        <th class="time">EX-ST</th>
        <th class="time">EX-TH</th>
        <th class="time">EX-DT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="blank_row">
        <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="dt" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_dt" class="time_input"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="add_new">Button</button>
```

Comment: --->  hi,i want to know does it will bind the event also is any of <td> content having event attached with that .?

Comment: No it'll not but if you want to do that you have an option read more about this topic [here](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)